# Why does the Wiener algebra not include all continuous functions: are there simple examples?

Tags: continuity, fourier-series

If $(c_n) (n \in \mathbf Z)$ is a family of complex numbers indexed by the positive and negative integers that is summable (i.e. the sum of their absolute values is finite) then $f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n \exp(inx)$ defines a continuous periodic function $f$ on the real line. All such functions build the Wiener algebra $A$. Has someone here a simple example showing that $A$ isn't the whole set of complex continuous periodic functions? In the theory of Fourier series there are examples with continuous functions having a Fourier series that doesn't converge everywhere; such functions might do the job, but they are always quite complicated. I am looking for simpler continuous functions not in $A$ if there is such a thing. Thanks

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series, specifically the discussion in the section on pointwise convergence.

Comment: C. Williams, what exactly do you mean from that section? I consider the examples given (where convergence isn't everywhere) as rather complicated (formula might look as still relativively simple, but what about the proof?) BTW is there no (known) example where the absol. values of the Four. coeff. of a cont. fct. f add up to infinity with "good" convergence of the Four. series to f (e.g. pointwise without exception)?